# view model in java (nested or not)

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, view

I am creating a web page (login.jsp) with 3 fields: 
1) **Login Id** is a text box - The `<input type="text">` Element 
2) **Password** is a text box - The `<input type="text">` Element 
3) **Language** is a drop down list - The `<select>` Element

I am creating a view model for this jsp. The jsp will use it to display data. I have called it ***LoginView***. And I think I have 2 choices:

Create a separate class for **Language** field:

```
public class LoginView implements java.io.Serializable ¨
    public String loginId;
    public String password;
    public List<LoginViewLanguage> loginViewLanguageList;
}
public class LoginViewLanguage implements java.io.Serializable ¨
    public String languageId;
    public String languageDescription;
}
```

Or create an inner class for **Language** field:

```
public class LoginView implements java.io.Serializable ¨
    public String loginId;
    public String password;
    public List<LoginViewLanguage> loginViewLanguageList;

    class LoginViewLanguage {
        public String languageId;
        public String languageDescription;
    }
}
```

Which one is the correct way and why?

Thanks

Comment: Use enum for your Language.

Comment: The Language data will be coming from database. There is a table **code_language** which has language_id int, language_description varchar(50) and active_flag bit columns. I will be picking the languages from that table with active_flag = 1. So I think I cannot use enum for Language. Correct?

Comment: yes your right but next time please provide more clearer information . gonna delete my answer. :) XD gonna think another solution

Comment: on my point of view  I prefer to use the separate class for reusability purpose. Because when you create  an inner class it means that it is only visible to class where you create it and on the same package depends on its access modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner class makes more sense when the usage is limited to the container class, event handling for ex.
In your case if the language is static list of id and description than you can have it as Enum  inner/standalone depending on usage in other parts of the project.

Comment: The language is not static list of id and descriptions. It is coming from database. Its possible that for one company, there is only one language defined: 1,English. And for another company, there may be two languages defined: 1,Spanish and 2,English

Comment: From you descriptions it seems you will need language through out your project,you should keep Language as a separate class,keeping coupling to the minimum

Comment: @srh In that case, I'd make the `LoginViewLanguage` a completely separate, top-level class, and fill it at the app level when the app starts (use a `ServletContextListener`).

Comment: There is a separate data model class for Language.
`public class CodeLanguage implements java.io.Serializable { private int languageId; private String languageDescription; private boolean activeFlag; // getters and setters 
}`

Comment: @srh you need to include the List of such language objects in your LoginView.